# Why is the bathtub water backing up into the shower?

Tags: plumbing

When the bathtub water runs out, it backs up into the shower and floods the whole floor. We have cleaned the drain pipes, but it still happens. What could be the problem?

Comment: How did you clean the drain pipes?

Answer (score 1):

The rate of flow and effective pressure from the bath is more than the drains ability to drain. This is normally associated with a clogged drain but if you say it's clean. The drain problem is somewhere after the pipes run from the shower. I had that problem previously and it ended up being roots in the drain. 
If the shower flows right after you let the water out then there is a blockage close by, but I would guess that the shower only gets water after a few minutes.

Comment: Sewer-root horror story: This exact same situation happened to me (plumber cleared roots out) but the roots kept coming back... Turns out when they resurfaced the street in front of my house some months before, they cracked a pipe... Now guess who got to pay for that? Well, my parents, but that's beside the point. We had a 15x15x15ft cube carved into the yard and a couple feet into the street for about a week. Pretty much a nightmare since we couldn't use any water at all. Yes, the bathroom situation was interesting...

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure because I am missing some details, but it look like you are missing some ventilation in your system. We got that problem one year and I had to go on the roof and then clean the vents that were clogged by some sort of bird's nest.  I hope that helps, good luck! ;)